# Prawn PDF: how to add images uploaded with dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, prawn, dragonfly-gem

I like to generate PDF-Files which also includes images uploaded by the user. The prawn gem works so far, and can also embed images located in the file system. 
My problem is that I want to include user uploaded images, and where these images are stored will probably change in the future (from file system to some cloud service). 
I use the dragonfly gem for handling the images, this uses rack to access the images and sometimes process them on the fly.

Now the simpliest idea does not work 
(with `report` being my object and `spot_image` my image field)

```
image report.spot_image

no implicit conversion of #<Class:0x007fc07ecf1110> into String
```

I tried also to open the file via http with open-uri. This should work, but it blocks on my development machine, I think because the development rails server is single threaded:

```
image_path = report.spot_image.remote_url
image_url = "#{view.request.protocol}\#view.request.host_with_port}
             /#{image_path.sub(/^\//,"")}"

image open(image_url)  # timeout in development-mode
```

It may probably work in production, but even then it does a needless http-request. Can I ask dragonfly (or rack) directly for the image? prawn uses duck-typing and needs some object that responds to `read` and `rewind` as image.

Comment: `It may probably work in production, but even then it does a needless http-request` - what do you mean by needless? If its a remote image than some component will have to do a http request to fetch it for you to embed

Answer (score 0):

I found relevant documentation about [dragonfly file handling](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/how-works/#using-content). The following did not work: 
The `report.spot_image.data` method returns the image data as string, but prawn recognizes the data as path instead of as image data. The dragonfly `tempfile` method returns a closed temporary file, but prawn does not recognize that it can open it.

I had success with the `file` method, which returns an open file handle. It is unclear if prawn is closing this file than. So I used the block-style method to make sure the file is closed:

```
   report.spot_image.file do |f|
       image f
   end
```

This works so far. (not yet tested with cloud storage)